# How to align some math items in an itemize list?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I would like to align some maths items listed in an `itemize` list.  Is this possible without hacking with lots of phantom symbols?  Here's a MWE to play and have fun with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Blablabla:
\medskip
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}
    \item Some comment: $y^2 = x$,
    \smallskip
    \item Another small comment: $a x = z$,
    \smallskip
    \item Insert a joke here: $x - y = z$.
\end{itemize}
\medskip
Blablabla.
\end{document}
```

Here's a small preview to make you laugh, with my issue shown in red:

[image]

As you have guessed, I want the maths expressions to be left aligned, while the text stays in place.  Is this funny trick possible?

Comment: You may want to accept one of these nice answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `eqparbox` for that. In

```
\eqmakebox[meow][l]{<content>}
```

`meow` is an identifier, all boxes with this identifier will have the same width after the second run, and `l` is the alignment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}

Blablabla:
\medskip
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}
    \item \eqmakebox[meow][l]{Some comment:} $y^2 = x$,
    \smallskip
    \item \eqmakebox[meow][l]{Another small comment:} $a x = z$,
    \smallskip
    \item \eqmakebox[meow][l]{Insert a joke here:} $x - y = z$.
\end{itemize}
\medskip
Blablabla.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would also like to encourage you to use the `enumitem` package instead of the more manual adjustments in the list. I will be happy to spell this out if needed.

Comment: What a funny tabby, you are!  ;-).  Is there any other trick to do this, without loading another package?

Comment: @Cham You could basically repeat what `eqparbox` does: collect the widths of the boxes, write them to the aux file and then make sure that all of them have the maximal width. The `eqmakebox` is not a big package that takes long to load.

Comment: @Cham I mean with `enumitem` you could just use something like `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=1ex,label={$\circ$}]` instead of adding `\smallskip` by hand and adding `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}`.

Comment: Ah yeah, I knew that last one.  Just forgot about it (there are so much options in LaTeX, I can't memorize all of them!).

Comment: Meow?  What do you think of my solution below?  Tabbing the tabbies may be cool.  ;-)

Comment: meow? What does it mean. Nothing explains this character string in eqparbox package documentation.

Comment: @Cham What kind of a cat are you that you do not know what meow means?? ;-) `meow` is used as a tag/identifier. All boxes tagged `meow` have the same width. You might want to build another set of equally wide boxes, and you could tag them `quack`, say. That is, all boxes with equal tags share the width of the widest box with that tag.

Answer (score 3):

The usage of `eqparbox` has [already been suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523505/4427). While the answer is mostly fine and the code works, it becomes tedious and error prone having to emit a different “meow” each time the construction is used.

The problem is that in the code `meow` stands for an arbitrary label, but this label should be ***unique*** for each series of `\eqparbox` bits.

Here's a simplification that also gets rid of all your manually added skips.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem,eqparbox}

\newenvironment{tabbeditems}
 {%
  \begin{itemize}[
    topsep=\medskipamount,
    itemsep=\smallskipamount,
    label=$\circ$,
  ]%
  \stepcounter{tabbeditem}
 }
 {\end{itemize}}
\newcounter{tabbeditem}
\renewcommand{\thetabbeditem}{\arabic{tabbeditem}TI}
\newcommand{\tabitem}[1]{\item\eqmakebox[\thetabbeditem][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}

Blablabla
\begin{tabbeditems}
\tabitem{Some comment:} $y^2 = x$,

\tabitem{Another small comment:} $a x = z$,

\tabitem{Insert a joke here:} $x - y = z$.
\end{tabbeditems}
Blablabla.
\begin{tabbeditems}
\tabitem{A comment:} $y^2 = x$,

\tabitem{A comment:} $a x = z$,

\tabitem{Joke:} $x - y = z$.
\end{tabbeditems}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the unique label is automatically supplied. It may take a couple of LaTeX run for the thing to synchronize.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which only requires the use of the `array` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in}, left=1.5in, top=0.5in,
            includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % amsmath package is loaded automatically by mathtools package
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcommand{\listtab}[1]{\begingroup\par\medskip%
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{tabular}{>{$\circ$\,\,} l L @{}}
     #1
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup\par\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Blablabla:
\listtab{
   Some comment:          & y^2 = x,\\
   Another small comment: & a x = z,\\
   Insert a joke here:    & x - y = z .}
Blablabla.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I was already loading the `tabto` package, I've found a nice solution to my issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

Blablabla:
\medskip
\begin{itemize}[label=$\circ$]
    \item Some comment: \tabto*{2in} $y^2 = x$,
    \smallskip
    \item Another small comment: \tabto*{2in} $a x = z$,
    \smallskip
    \item Insert a joke here: \tabto*{2in} $x - y = z$.
\end{itemize}
\medskip
Blablabla.
\end{document}
```

This tabby trick does the trick.  However, I have to eye adjust the tabbies, so I'm not sure this is a proper solution.

About the `tabto` package:
http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabto/tabto-doc.pdf

Comment: Meow! (no translation needed)

Answer (score 0):

The following is similar to an [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) approach, using boxes to space things out evenly. Place the smaller items inside `\makebox[0pt][l]` (`l`eft-aligned, zero-width) boxes with the widest element inside a `\phantom` to have the appropriate horizontal spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Blablabla:
\begin{itemize}[
  label=$\circ$,
  before=\medskip,
  itemsep=\smallskipamount,
  after=\medskip
]
  \item \makebox[0pt][l]{Some comment:}\phantom{Another small comment: }$y^2 = x$,

  \item Another small comment: $a x = z$,

  \item \makebox[0pt][l]{Insert a joke here:}\phantom{Another small comment: }$x - y = z$.
\end{itemize}
Blablabla.

\end{document}
```